# How to create a dictionary in Excel in order to replace words with keys?

Tags: excel, dictionary, replace, excel-formula, vlookup

Not sure if this is even possible, but before I write a script I wanted to ask... I have two columns in Excel, something like this:

```
 EC            Accession_ID
[3.1.1.1]   GRMZM2G057491_P01   
[2.1.1] GRMZM2G036921_P01   
[2.6.1.5]   GRMZM2G084279_P01   
[2.6.1.5]   GRMZM2G143767_P01
```

About 1,300 of those. Each `EC` corresponds to the `Accession_ID` in the same row. I have a list of `Accession_ID`s (roughly 800) that I'd want to replace with the matching `EC` number (using the list above) but they are not in the same order.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) can help you

Comment: Yes, definitely, if they match the accession ID next to them

Comment: Someone posted a correct answer and then deleted it as I was about to accept it :( I used VLOOKUP. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid VLOOKUP would not suit in your case because the value to be looked up is to the left of the linking value. However INDEX and MATCH in combination should suit:

[image: SO21737468 example]

Assumes your two lists are in the same workbook (and on same sheet for the sake of the image).

*Edit* assuming different sheets and better image:

[image: SO21737468 second example]

Here Sheet1 ColumnA has been given the name `EClist` and Sheet1 ColumnB `AccList`.

*Edit* In view of your preference for VLOOKUP and given that I was wrong to expect someone else to have come along by now and offered that solution (again), I suggest copying ColumnA of Sheet1 to ColumnC and in B1 of your (assumed) other sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!B:C,2,0)
```

copied down to suit.